# Subject table for an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE expected

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to execute an upsert using SQLAlchemy. Here is my code:

```
def add_product(session, item):
    insert_statement = insert(Product.__tablename__).values(
        id=item[0],
        name=item[1],
        price=item[2],
        units_sold=item[3]
    )
    do_update_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
        price=item[2],
        units_sold=item[3]
    )
    session.execute(do_update_statement)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= Column(String)
    price= Column(Float)
    units_sold= Column(Integer)
```

But, when I try to execute this, I get the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: subject table for an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE expected, got 'products'.
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Also, are there better options to create an upsert operation?

Comment: `insert(Product)` or `insert(Product.__table__)`.

Comment: ... or `insert(Product.__table__)` should work as well

Comment: It might be related to SQLALchemy last version (1.4), check what happens downgrading to 1.3.X to have more clues

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `schema.Table` object to `insert`:

```py
insert(Base.metadata.tables[Product.__tablename__]).values(...)
```

Comment: Surely this is not the correct syntax..?

Comment: It's an example, so you need to fill in the `...` @scrollout

Comment: I mean the syntax is super verbose

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I had `sqlalchemy==1.4.26`. I rolled back to the version `1.3.24` and this error disappeared.

```
pip uninstall sqlalchemy
pip istall sqlalchemy==1.3.24
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case It was a typo in the update statement rather then using the model class `Evaluation` I used the argument `evaluation` : `sqlalchemy_update(evaluation)` so I got the error below, the solution was simply by using the model class `sqlalchemy_update(Evaluation)`:

```
subject table for an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE expected, got EvaluationUpdate(name='Evaluation1 updated', industry_id=2, published=False, created_by=UUID('e765e925-fd31-4461-9fa4-4b1093477522'), created_at=None, updated_at=None).
```

Correct code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import update as sqlalchemy_update
from app.models.evaluation import Evaluation

async def updateEvaluationItem(id: int, evaluation: EvaluationUpdate, db: Session = Depends(get_async_session)):
    try:
        query = sqlalchemy_update(Evaluation).where(
            Evaluation.id == id).values(**evaluation.dict())
        ...
    ...
```